# Passing data from one js to another js

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have two js: (1st) is where i can add the map and where i can click a button and draw shapes(geozone) and (2nd) is where i can change color and opacity of the shapes using colorpicker and summernotes.

I can get the color in the colorpicker in the (2nd) js using

```
$('#colorpicker'+no).colorpicker().on('changeColor', function() {
            var no = $(this).attr('map'); 
            var color = $('#txtGeoColor'+no).val();
            console.log("color1 : " , color);
        });
```

and its inside the document.ready(function()).

is it possible to call the color from the (2nd) js and pass it to (1st) js inside this code:

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click", ".btnCircleDraw",function(){
        var circleDrawer = new L.Draw.Circle(map, {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: (must call the color here)
            }
        });   
        circleDrawer.enable();
    });
```

Comment: i don't know what `colorpicker` library you're using, but usually objects have their own getter function, so my best guess would be to consult the documentation of said colorpicker and use the method to get the selected color, then onclick, invoke the getter method

Comment: try embing the first $('#colorpicker'+no).colorpicker().... inside a function and call it inside (color:callingfunction())

Answer (score 0):

To use the color variable inside the 2nd file. you need to import 1st file above the second file. like

File 1:

```
var color = '';
$('#colorpicker'+no).colorpicker().on('changeColor', function() {
            var no = $(this).attr('map'); 
            color = $('#txtGeoColor'+no).val();
            console.log("color1 : " , color);
        });
```

File 2:

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click", ".btnCircleDraw",function(){
        var circleDrawer = new L.Draw.Circle(map, {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: color
            }
        });   
        circleDrawer.enable();
    });
```

Always keep in mind that import file 1 before file 2 because file 2 contain a color variable that is initialized and assign in file 1.

File Where both js file will consume.

```
<script src="file1.js">
<script src="file2.js">
```